# NSUndoManager and Undo/Redo Menu Items "disconnected" from each other

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsundomanager

In a Cocoa application I implemented Undo/Redo and the functionality works as expected. The problem is that both ("Undo" and "Redo") menu items seem to be "disconnected" from NSUndoManager in use, in the sense that they are not disabled/enabled in accordance with the undo/redo stacks sizes. They remain always enabled and they also do not update their "action name"

```
[undoManager setActionName:@"Move To Trash"];
```

seems ineffective. Menu items always read "Undo" and "Redo". Both items sent their actions to `First Responder` and actions work.

Since the application is not `NSDocument` based, I also tried implementing

```
- (NSUndoManager *)windowWillReturnUndoManager:(NSWindow *)sender;
```

in window's delegate as I read in a few places could help. The method is called on both action and when undoing but this doesn't change anything. Everything behaves as without this delegate method.

What else might I be doing wrong or missing?

Comment: Does the first responder return the correct undo manager?

Comment: Since the actions work I'd assume "yes". What/how else can I check that?

Comment: Good point. Are the menu items always enabled? Is `undo:` implemented? Any other undo managers (`NSTextView`)? Post a [mre] please.

Comment: Menu items are always enabled. There is no "custom" `undo:` implemented. It goes to first responder, which should be the window. I am not aware of any other undo managers. There are some `NSTextField`s but no `NSTextView`s in the XIB. Posting example is probably not feasible as the application is relatively complex. I'll see if I can reproduce it somehow outside the application environment but can't bet on it

Answer (score 0):

In case somebody else is on a path to lose as much time on this as I have…

The reason for observed misbehaviour in this particular case was that the "Edit" `NSMenu` containing both "Undo" and "Redo" `NSMenuItem`s did NOT have "Auto Enables Items" set/checked. After checking the appropriate checkbox in Interface Builder not only both menuitems began to get properly disabled/enabled but also their textual content started to get adjusted in accordance with `NSUndoManager`'s `setActionName:(NSString *)name` calls.